# MySQL No database selected rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, figaro-ruby

I got something like this when i hit rake db:migrate 
Im using figaro in my app, its my first time with this gem any mysql so I cant get what excatly is wrong.
Thanks in advance :)

> Mysql2::Error: No database selected: CREATE TABLE `schema_migrations` (`version` varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=InnoDB

*database.yml*

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: <%= ENV["DB_USER"] %>
  password: <%= ENV["DB_PASSWORD"] %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV["DB_DATABASE_DEV"] %>


test:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV["DB_DATABSE_TEST"] %>


production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['DB_DATABASE_PRODUCTION'] %>
```

*application.yml*

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: password

development:
  <<: *default
  database: dev

test:
  <<: *default
  database: test_db
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough point to ask in comment, but it seems you're trying to run migration without creating a schema first.

Run `rails db:create` to create the schema first. For example, if you don't have the a database named "dev" in your MySQL, this command will do so.

```
rails db:create
```

To set specific environment

```
rails db:create RAILS_ENV=test
```

Then you run can`rails db:migrate`.

To destroy a schema if you need one:

```
rails db:drop
```

**You're Using ENV**

Though it might not be related, have you set up your ENV properly before running the command?

For Windows, you can add those, for example, DB_USER to `system environment`

Just press Start and type `system environment` >> `Environment Variables...` >> `New...`

```
Variable Name: DB_USER
Variable Value: your_username
```

Note: You might have to restart your system for the environment to work.

Or if you don't have time, simply in your terminal you're running rails s:

```
C:\Sites\ProjectName> set DB_USER=your_username
C:\Sites\ProjectName> set DB_PASSWORD=your_username
C:\Sites\ProjectName> rails s
```

The same steps for Linux, but I don't know the specific command. Some prefer to use .env file.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this trouble a couple days ago, and it's very annoying because Rails tried to create dev and test db's when in dev environment. Nothing worked.

I ended up hard-coding `database:` into `database.yml`, and let Figaro manage credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I runned the same issue today.

Ensure you have dotenv-rails gem installed and that "DB_DATABASE_DEV" has a value in your .env file.

Also, make sure your database has been created.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when your `database.yml` does not include `database: some_database` part or when database name is empty. In your case you can use one of few options:

#### Option 1: run migrations with database name env variable included

```sh
DB_DATABASE_DEV=your_dev_db_name rails db:<task>
```

#### Option 2: use hard-coded db name in your `database.yml` file

```
# database.yml
development:
  <<: *default
  database: my_development_database
```

#### Option 3: make sure that env variables are correctly loaded

To do so in linux, simply write in terminal:

```
echo ${DB_DATABASE_DEV}
```

On windows terminal you need to write this:

```
echo %DB_DATABASE_DEV%
```

If you get no content then this env variable is not set